# GXT Resize Grid and FieldSet when grid store is filtered

Tags: java, gxt

I have a fieldset with a grid inside. I'm applying a filter to the grid store and want both the fieldset and the grid to resize when the filter is applied. I have the listener on the store but I can't for the life of me figure out how to resize both components.

I'm using GXT 2.4

Here's some sample code to give context:

```
final FieldSet fieldSet = new FieldSet();
fieldSet.setHeading("Example");
fieldSet.setCollapsible(true);
fieldSet.setCheckboxToggle(true);
fieldSet.setExpanded(false);
mainFieldSet.add(fieldSet,new RowData(-1,-1,new Margins(10,0,0,0)));

ListStore<MyModel> store = new ListStore<MyModel>();
store.add(myModels);

CheckBoxSelectionModel<MyModel> sm = new CheckBoxSelectionModel<MyModel>();

List<ColumnConfig> columns = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
columns.add(sm.getColumn());
ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig("id", "Id", 40);
column.setSortable(false);
columns.add(column);
column = new ColumnConfig("name", "Label",280);
column.setSortable(false);
columns.add(column);

final Grid<MyModel> grid = new Grid<MyModel>(store, new ColumnModel(columns));
grid.addPlugin(sm);
grid.setBorders(true);
grid.setSelectionModel(sm);
fieldSet.add(grid);

grid.getStore().addStoreListener(new StoreListener<MyModel>() {
    public void storeFilter(StoreEvent<MyModel> se) {
        // Need something here to resize both grid and fieldSet
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it! The `fieldSet` and `grid` both need to have `setAutoHeight(true)` and fire the following events from the `StoreListener`:

```
grid.getStore().addStoreListener(new StoreListener<OptionModel>() {
  public void storeFilter(StoreEvent<OptionModel> se) {
    questionFieldSet.fireEvent(Events.Expand);
    questionFieldSet.fireEvent(Events.Resize);
  }
});
```